# Preload all Relationships

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an ERM similar to this one:

```
--------     --------     --------
|ModelA|-----|ModelB|-----|ModelC|
--------     --------     --------
```

I get ModelA and its ModelBs with the following:

```
modela = Repo.get(ModelA,1)
modela = preload(modela, :modelb)
```

Now I can access `ModelB`s with `modela.modelb`. But how can I preload `ModelC` aswell? When I print my modelA, it says, that modelc is not loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't comment yet but you have to define the nested relationship in ModelA. See [`Ecto.Schema`](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html)

`has_one :model_c,  through: [:model_b, :model_c]`

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a list to `Repo.preload` to load multiple associations. You can even pass a keyword list to preload nested associations.
I also find it useful to load everything that I need in the query itself (those two options below are equivalent):

```
query = from m in ModelA, preload: [modelb: :modelc]
Repo.get(query, 1)

Repo.get(ModelA, 1) |> Repo.preload(modelb: :modelc)
```

You can also pass tuples with `{association_name, query}` for advanced preloding - especially useful in many associations to specify ordering.

You can read more of the documentation on preloads in the [`Ecto.Query.preload/3` docs](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3)

Comment: If I do it like this, it says, that ModelA doesn't have a association to ModelC

Answer (score 2):

You can preload both Model B and it's Model C associations using one piped Repo query, without having to include an association between Model A and Model C in Model A's model definition:

```
modela = Repo.get(ModelA, 1)
         |> Repo.preload(:modelb)
         |> Repo.preload(modelb: :modelc)
```