# Preload nested associations in ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have 4 models, which are associated as

**Form**

```
has_many :form_fields, FormField, on_delete: :delete_all
has_many :fields, through: [:form_fields, :field]
has_many :conditions, Condition, on_delete: :delete_all
```

**Field**

```
has_many :form_fields, FormField, on_delete: :delete_all
has_many :forms, through: [:form_fields, :form]
has_many :conditions, Condition, on_delete: :delete_all
```

**FormField**

```
belongs_to :form, Form
belongs_to :field, Field
```

**Condition**

```
belongs_to :field, Field
belongs_to :form, Form
```

I want to write a query to get a form whose `id` is known along with the `fields` and the `conditions`(common for both `Form` & `Field`) inside every field

Eg: To get a form with `id` as 1,

```
%{
    id: 1,
    fields: [
        %{
            id: 1,
            conditions: [
                %{
                    id: 1
                    form_id: 1,
                    field_id: 1
                },
                %{
                    id: 2
                    form_id: 1,
                    field_id: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        %{
            id: 2,
            conditions: [
                %{
                    id: 3
                    form_id: 1,
                    field_id: 2
                },
                %{
                    id: 4
                    form_id: 1,
                    field_id: 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My question was marked as possible duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710272) which was very straight. But my situation is slightly different from that. Please take a look at both the questions and help me overcome this step.

Comment: And did you try anything from the documentation (https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preload all Relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710272/preload-all-relationships)

Comment: @Dogbert Yes I looked into the docs. But I couldn't achieve what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. The below query worked

```
form_conditions =
  Condition
  |> where(form_id: ^id)
form =
  Form
  |> where(id: ^id)
  |> preload(fields: [conditions: ^form_conditions])
  |> Repo.one!
```